# Can't view my TextView inside buttons onClickListener

Tags: java, android, textview

Good morning everyone,

I wanted to find out why my textview's won't show up in my app. I declared them inside a button's onClick method, so its like once the buttons been clicked, pop them up. Its basically for an "enter" type of button, where if the user enters the correct answer, display correct in the textview, otherwise wrong.

```
public void Easy12(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = (int) rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    int b = (int) rand.nextInt(100)+1;
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_label);
    String aString = Integer.toString(a);
    String bString = Integer.toString(b);
    String display = aString + " + " + bString + " =";
    tv.setText(display);
    final int c = a + b;

    final Button buttonhash = (Button) findViewById(R.id.keypad_hash);
    buttonhash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.USERentry);
            if(edittext.getText().equals(c)){
                final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightwrong_label);
                answerLabel.setText(R.string.answer_correct);
                answerLabel.setTextColor(R.color.correct_color);
            }
            else
            {
                final TextView answerLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rightwrong_label);
                answerLabel.setText(R.string.answer_wrong);
                answerLabel.setTextColor(R.color.wrong_color);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

I had to make separate textviews that call the same textview because it wouldn't recognize them because of the brackets. This method is part of my Game class, which just displays an expression and checks to see whether the users answer is correct or not by pressing the a button on the screen. If anybody knows whats wrong please share. Thank you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/question_label"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/rightwrong_label"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<EditText
android:id="@+id/USERentry"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
android:textColor="@color/user_txt_color"/>
<TableLayout....
```

Comment: Can you share the layout code as well?

Comment: yup, uploaded the layout

Comment: Can you do a quick log inside onClick to see if the app goes inside onClick when you click the button?

Answer (score 1):

This is because your View is not getting updated on which you are writing your textViews. Try refreshing your view by redrawing it or pass some intent to see if the writing part is working or not

Comment: err how would I do that? By calling invalidate()? Sorry I'm novice

Comment: You are performing all these activities in one layout itself right? I mean the point where is the button clicked and where should be the textviews displayed?

Comment: Ya everythings happening in one layout. Once the button is clicked, it should display the string inside the textview in the same screen

Answer (score 1):

OR else , if u r interested use "TOAST" method ,

```
Toast.makeText(LoginpageActivity.this, "Write your text here to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Here ," LoginpageActivity"  s the current class name

Comment: Thanks, I might do that, but I can see some other problem areas with this approach. Thanks for your input.